# Maximum update depth exceeded React SignOut using react-auth-kit

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to creat a react.js app and I am using react-auth-kit for authentication. I am facing this error when i try to logout, even though the logout is working fine but it throughs this error.

**Here are my Routes**

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"
import {RequireAuth} from 'react-auth-kit'
import Register from './Components/Register';
import Login from './Components/Login';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import Home from './Components/Home';

export default function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}></Route>
            <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>}></Route>


                <Route path={'/'} element={
                <RequireAuth loginPath={'/login'}>
                  <Header />
                    <Home></Home>
                  <Footer />
                </RequireAuth>
            }/>

        </Routes>

    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

**And this is my Logout component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSignOut } from 'react-auth-kit'

export default function Logout() {
    const signOut = useSignOut()
  return (
    <>
      <span onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign Out</span>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is error? I don't see that

Comment: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

Comment: After logout and successfully redirecting back to login page but on login page this above error popup comes up @EageringDev

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.